# For loop not storing variables?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Temperature Information</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    //declare variables
        var BR = "<br />";
        var ES = " ";
        var counter;
        var temp = [counter];
        var max = 0;
        var min = 0;
        var tempTot;
        var tempAve;
        //loop
        for (counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter++) {
            tempTot = tempTot + temp[counter];
            temp[counter] = prompt("Enter the temperature for noon on day #" + counter,ES);
            temp[counter] = parseFloat(temp[counter]);
            if (temp[counter] == temp[1]){
                temp[counter] = max;
                temp[counter] = min;
            }else if (temp[counter + 1] > temp[counter] && temp[counter] != temp[1]){
                temp[counter] = max;
            }else if (temp[counter + 1] < temp[counter] && temp[counter] != temp[1]){
                temp[counter] = min;
            }
            tempTot = tempTot + temp[counter];
        }
        tempAve = tempTot/4;
        //display info
        document.write("The average temperature is: " + tempAve + BR);
        document.write("The maximum temperature is: " + max + BR);
        document.write("The minimum temperature is: " + min + BR);
    </script>
</body>
```

It is supposed to take info for the temperature for 5 days, display the average, max, and min. Everything seems to run fine, but it only displays the outcomes with a null. Am I doing something wrong? I feel like I am thinking too much about this.

Comment: What `var temp = [counter];` is supposed to do?

Comment: There are many things wrong with your code.

Comment: You're accessing temperature values you haven't filled in yet, via `temp[counter + 1]`. Those will be `undefined`, which will coerce to `NaN` when you compare it to a number. Comparisons involving `NaN` are always false. Additionally, although it's not causing a problem in the code above, array indexes start at 0, not 1. I recommend stepping through the code in the debugger built into your browser, watching what the values of your various variables are, etc. It's like turning on the lights in a dark room, and it's not something to wait to learn until later. Beginners need debuggers. :-)

Comment: There are all kinds of crazy in here but well done for not using jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of minor errors in your code.  Using the [browser's debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) or using `console.log` to check the state would help you figure out what is wrong.  For example, your `temp` array's 0 element is `undefined` so when you do math on it, bad things happen ;).  Also, it is easier to process your array once you have all of the elements instead doing it "on the fly".  And finally, always check if the javascript library can do something for you (Math.min) instead of writing it....

oh, and I also put your code into its own function.  If you look at your code in the debugger, you'll see that your variables are now all nicely contained in their own scope instead of co-mingling with the global scope.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Temperature Information</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
      var tempInformation = function() {
        var BR = "<br />";
        var ES = " ";
        var temp = [];

        for (var counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
            var input = prompt("Enter the temperature for noon on day #" + (counter + 1), ES);
            temp[counter] = parseFloat(input);
        }

        var sum = temp.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
        var avg = sum / temp.length;

        document.write("The average temperature is: " + avg + BR);
        document.write("The maximum temperature is: " + Math.max.apply(null, temp) + BR);
        document.write("The minimum temperature is: " + Math.min.apply(null, temp) + BR);
      }

      tempInformation();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was much more simple than I thought